# Hibernate in Intelli J IDEA

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

Someone please show me how to use hibernate framework in intelli j IDEA just simple console app ?
I migration from netbean to IDEA it totally difference.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Can you recommend me some books or some tutorials for my problem? Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mix up different topics:

- **Hibernate** is an implementation of JPA (Java Persistence API) and part of Java EE
- **IntelliJ / Netbeans** are IDEs (integrated development environment) which allow you to create and deploy applications, for example using Java EE

So if you want to make use of JPA / Hibernate, you have to create for example a Java EE application and deploy it within a WAR file into the application server of your choice, e.g. GlassFish or WildFly.

I assume you had some click-here-and-then-click-there tutorial on how to create a JPA application in Netbeans and don't finde the same in IntelliJ. - But much more important would be to learn what JPA is and how to use it in an application and only then click it together within an IDE.

Always a good reference is the [Oracle Jave EE tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/), specifically the chapter about [JPA](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro.htm#BNBPZ).

You may also use JPA in standard Java, see for example [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-tutorial-setting-jpa-java).